# How to use Google Apps Script to authenticate SaxoTrader

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, oauth-2.0

I want to use **Google Apps** Script to create a program that allows me to retrieve prices from `SaxoTrader`, and make trades using their simulation account.
I'm stuck at the **authorization** step. I cannot seem to get authorization/ access for it.

it says access denied. im not sure why? could someone help me? thank you!

```js
var clientID = "c8703eba07e44f96804a3baa195b96de"
var clientSecret = "089205e12ad74b6787f02f77a0908d2c"
var authorizationBaseUrl = "https://sim.logonvalidation.net/authorize" 
var tokenUrl = "https://sim.logonvalidation.net/token" 
// Refer to notes from "https://www.developer.saxo/openapi/learn/oauth-authorization-code-grant"


//Create the OAuth2 service
function getService() {
  return OAuth2.createService('Saxo')
  // Set the endpoint URLs
  .setAuthorizationBaseUrl(authorizationBaseUrl)
  .setTokenUrl(tokenUrl)
  
  // Set the client ID and secret
  .setClientId(clientID)
  .setClientSecret(clientSecret)
  
  // Set other parameters required by Saxo
  .setParam('response_type', 'code')
  
  //Set the name of callback function to be invoked to complete OAuth flow.
  .setCallbackFunction("authCallback")
  
  //Set the property story where authorized tokens should be persisted
  .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties());
}

// Direct the user to the authorization URL
function showSidebar() {
  var service = getService();
  if (!service.hasAccess()) {
    var authorizationUrl = service.getAuthorizationUrl();
    var template = HtmlService.createTemplate(
      '<a href="<?= authorizationUrl ?>" target="_blank">Authorize</a>. ' +
      'Reopen the sidebar when the authorization is complete.');
    template.authorizationUrl = authorizationUrl;
    var page = template.evaluate();
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(page);
  } else {
    //...
  }
}

//Handles the OAuth callback
function authCallback(request) {
  var service = getService();
  var authorized = service.handleCallback(request);
  if (authorized) {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("Success!");
  } else {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("Denied!");
  }
}

//Get the access token and make requests to the API
function makerequest() {
  var service = getService();
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://gateway.saxobank.com/sim/openapi/port/v1/users/me", {
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken()
    }
  });
  var results = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().setValues(results);  
}

// Logs the redirect URI to register
function logRedirectUri() {
  Logger.log(OAuth2.getRedirectUri());
}
```

Comment: You just posted your Client Secret in a public post. Make sure to invalidate it and make a new one. And do NOT post it.

Comment: At what point does this error appear? What steps did you (as a user) do until that point?